# Ember JS and Multiple single page apps

Tags: ember.js

Say I have a web app - a large, complex, rails app, like an accounting application.  I see a use for several single page apps instead of the typical rails round tripping pages.  For example, I can see a user better served with an intuitive single page/dynamic app for:

- Creating Bank Reconciliation
- Creating an Invoice
- Filling out a Time Report
- etc..

These are all distinct one page apps...

All the ember apps I see are single page and single purpose.

I want to have many single page apps, built with ember.  How would that look with respect to:

Routes: I'd have a combination of server routes and client routes.  How would that look in Ember?  Serve different Ember applications, each with their own application router and routes?

Templates: Would all my "applets" get compiled and pushed down to the client on load? Or would I leverage require.js and load each single page app depending on if they're navigated to?
...

Can anyone help with those two questions?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: FYI - I wound up hosting different client "modules" on their own subdomain and then used rack-cors on the server to serve different sub-domains.  I also created a shared repo for some common client functionality.  It's pretty small.

Comment: can you provide more information about how you do? How did you solve common application concerns such as common menu, authorization & authentication. Did you merge them in a single page or were all your apps separated?

Answer (score 2):

> Routes: I'd have a combination of server routes and client routes. How would that look in Ember? Serve different Ember applications, each with their own application router and routes?

Depends on how much overlap there is in terms of features. For sure you could serve different Ember applications with their own router and routes. In that case you would probably also write a shared library with common base classes and mixins.

An alternative would be to have a single ember application that looks and behaves very differently depending on the route. That's where I would start until you have a good feel for ember and see a compelling reason to split things apart.

> Templates: Would all my "applets" get compiled and pushed down to the client on load? Or would I leverage require.js and load each single page app depending on if they're navigated to? ...

Path of least resistance in rails is to use sprockets to compile and package your templates - once compiled they are just javascript. Typically a rails app will bundle all javascript into application.js and include that on load. An alternative would be to split application-specific code and templates into app1.js, app2.js, etc. and load each when the app is navigated to.

Comment: I've already worked with Ember a bit - and with respect to your first answer - starting with a single app - How would that look in the router file? Two different "root" urls with a nest of items below it?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using a PODS structure and then you can have routes like

```
/app1/
  /route1
  /route2  
/app2/
  /route1
  /route2
etc...
```

If you generate with pods structure you folders e.g.
`ember generate route app1\route1`

you will end up with a good folder structure that you can split up later, something like:

```
   /app
       /pods/
            /app1
                 /route1
                    route.js
                    controller.js
                    template.hbs
                 /route2
                    route.js
                    controller.js
                    template.hbs
            /app2
                 /route1
                    route.js
                    controller.js
                    template.hbs
                 /route2
                    route.js
                    controller.js
                    template.hbs
```

Comment: Here is the document of Pod structure: https://ember-cli.com/user-guide/#pod-structure