# Ember CRUD application

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

Hello I am trying to develop stock list data along with CRUD application for assignment purpose but only stock list data is getting displayed. Here is my code. Its not displaying the other part (i.e. CRUD part) and its not showing any error as well. I am very new to ember I think it might be some silly mistake but I've tried lot of stuff but I am lost as its not throwing any error. I am not looking or any backed neither I am planning to save data. I just want to show CRUD functionality of EMBER.js some thing like this of **[angular](https://jsfiddle.net/viralpatel/72vT5/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=72vT5)**

Here is my HTML

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
  <title>Ember.js</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />

  <!-- EmberJS dependencies -->
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://builds.handlebarsjs.com.s3.amazonaws.com/handlebars-v1.3.0.js"></script>
  <script src="http://builds.emberjs.com/tags/v1.8.1/ember.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://builds.emberjs.com/tags/v1.0.0-beta.11/ember-data.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ember-localstorage-adapter/0.3.1/localstorage_adapter.js"></script>

  <!-- Lightstreamer JavaScript Client library -->
  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.1.9/require.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://demos.lightstreamer.com/commons/lightstreamer.js"></script>

  <!-- EmberJS code application -->
  <script src="js/stockListDemoApp.js"></script>
      <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="stock">
    <div id="wrap">
      <div id="top">
        <a id="logoEmber" href="http://emberjs.com" target="_blank"><img src="images/ember_logo.png" alt="EMBERLOGO" hspace="0" border="0" /></a>
        <div id="title">STOCK-LIST</div>
      </div>
         <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2" width="780" border="0" >
        <thead>
          <tr class="tableTitle">
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Last</td>
            <td>Time</td>
            <td>Change</td>
            <td>Bid Size</td>
            <td>Bid</td>
            <td>Ask</td>
            <td>Ask Size</td>
            <td>Min</td>
            <td>Max</td>
            <td>Ref.</td>
            <td>Open</td>
          </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
          {{#each item in model}}
          <tr {{bind-attr class="item.isOdd:colOdd:colEven"}}>
            <td><div {{bind-attr class="item.isOdd:stockNameOdd:stockNameEven"}}>{{item.stock_name}}</div></td>
            <td>{{item.last_price}}</td>
            <td>{{item.time}}</td>
            <td>{{item.pct_change}}</td>
            <td>{{item.bid_quantity}}</td>
            <td>{{item.bid}}</td>
            <td>{{item.ask}}</td>
            <td>{{item.ask_quantity}}</td>
            <td>{{item.min}}</td>
            <td>{{item.max}}</td>
            <td>{{item.ref_price}}</td>
            <td>{{item.open_price}}</td>
          </tr>
          {{/each}}
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <div class="disc">Simulated market data.</div>
    </div>
  </br>
  </br>
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
      <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>Welcome!</h1>
        <p>This app demonstrates CRUD with validation in Ember.js</p>
      </div>
    </script>

    <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="products">
      <h1>Products</h1>
      {{outlet}}
    </script>

    <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="products/index">
      <table id="products_table" class="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Author</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th><button type="button" class="btn btn-default new-button" {{action "new"}}><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></button></th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {{#each product in model}}
            <tr {{bind-attr id=product.htmlID}}>
              <td class="name">{{#link-to "products.show" product}}{{product.name}}{{/link-to}}</td>
              <td class="author">{{product.author}}</td>
              <td class="price">{{product.price}}</td>
              <td class="action-buttons"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default edit-button" {{action "edit" product}}><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></button>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default delete-button" {{action "delete" product}}><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></button></td>
            </tr>
          {{/each}}
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <p id="products_count">Total: {{controllers.products.productsCount}} products.</p>
    </script>

    <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="products/show">
      <h2><span class="name">{{name}}</span></h2>
      <p>By <span class="author">{{author}}</span></p>
      <p><strong>$<span class="price">{{price}}</span></strong></p>
      <p><span class="description">{{description}}</span></p>
      <p class="action-buttons"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default edit-button" {{action "edit" model}}><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default delete-button" {{action "delete" model}}><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></button></p>
      <p>{{#link-to 'products' class="index-link"}}Back to products index{{/link-to}}</p>
    </script>

    <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="products/edit">
      <h2>{{#if isNew}}New{{else}}Edit{{/if}} Product</h2>
      {{#form-for controller id="form-product" wrapper="bootstrap"}}
        {{#input name}}
          {{label-field name text="Product"}}
          {{input-field name class="form-control" autofocus="true"}}
          {{#if view.showError}}
            {{error-field name}}
          {{/if}}
        {{/input}}
        {{#input author}}
          {{label-field author text="Author"}}
          {{input-field author class="form-control"}}
          {{#if view.showError}}
            {{error-field author}}
          {{/if}}
        {{/input}}
        {{#input description}}
          {{label-field description text="Description"}}
          {{input-field description class="form-control"}}
          {{#if view.showError}}
            {{error-field description}}
          {{/if}}
        {{/input}}
        {{#input price}}
          {{label-field price text="Price"}}
          {{input-field price class="form-control"}}
          {{#if view.showError}}
            {{error-field price}}
          {{/if}}
        {{/input}}
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary save-button" {{action "save" model}}>Save</button>
        {{#if isNew}}
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default cancel-button" {{action "delete" model}}>Cancel</button>
        {{else}}
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default cancel-button" {{action "cancel" model}}>Cancel</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger delete-button" {{action "delete" model}}>Delete</button>
        {{/if}}
      {{/form-for}}
    </script>
  </script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ember-data.js/1.0.0-beta.8/ember-data.min.js"></script>
    <!-- ember-easyForm -->
    <script src="http://builds.dockyard.com.s3.amazonaws.com/ember-easyForm/canary/shas/add6a40a68c8b081557a9011cf99ea255414e1b1/ember-easyForm.min.js"></script>
    <!-- ember-validations -->
    <script src="http://builds.dockyard.com.s3.amazonaws.com/ember-validations/canary/shas/2ff28c6ba4d227b0f863b327cdff23c381c37afb/ember-validations.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
and here is my app.js
App = Ember.Application.create();
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
     return $.getJSON('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?' +
                  'v=1.0&num=50&q=https://news.google.com/news/feeds?output=rss&callback=?')
         .then(function(data){
         return data.responseData.feed.entries.map(function(entry){
            var post = {}; 
            post.title = entry.title;
            return post;
         });
     });
 }});
window.App = Ember.Application.create();
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.FixtureAdapter.extend({
  namespace: 'ember-crud'
});
Ember.EasyForm.Config.registerWrapper('bootstrap', {
  formClass: '',
  fieldErrorClass: 'has-error',
  inputClass: 'form-group',
  errorClass: 'help-block error',
  hintClass: 'help-block',
  labelClass: ''
});
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('products', function() {
    this.route('new');
    this.route('show', {path: '/:product_id'});
    this.route('edit', {path: '/:product_id/edit'});
  });
});
App.Product = DS.Model.extend(Ember.Validations.Mixin, {
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  author: DS.attr('string'),
  description: DS.attr('string'),
  price: DS.attr('number'),

  // To identify html tag for a Product.
  htmlID: function() {
    return 'product' + this.get('id');
  }.property('id'),

  validations: {
    name: {
      presence: true
    },
    price: {
      presence: true,
      numericality: {
        greaterThanOrEqualTo: 0
      }
    }
  }
});

App.resetFixtures = function() {
  App.Product.FIXTURES = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'Ember.js in Action',
      author: 'Joachim Haagen Skeie',
      description: 'Ember.js in Action is a crisp tutorial that introduces the Ember.js framework and shows you how to build production-quality web applications.',
      price: 44.99
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: 'Building Web Applications with Ember.js',
      author: 'Jesse Cravens & Thomas Brady',
      description: 'This guide provides example-driven instructions on how to develop applications using Ember, one of the most popular JavaScript frameworks available.',
      price: 29.99
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: 'The Ember.js Way',
      author: 'Brian Cardarella & Alex Navasardyan',
      description: "Inspired by Addison-Wesley's classic The Rails Way series, The Ember.js Way crystallizes all that's been learned about Ember.js development into a start-to-finish approach that works.",
      price: 39.99
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      name: 'Instant Ember.JS Application Development: How-to',
      author: 'Marc Bodmer',
      description: 'A practical guide that provides you with clear step-by-step examples. The in-depth examples take into account the key concepts and give you a solid foundation to expand your knowledge and your skills.',
      price: 20.69
    }
  ];
};
App.resetFixtures();
App.ProductsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.find('product');
  },
  actions: {
    // Redirect to new form.
    new: function() {
      this.transitionTo('products.new');
    },
    // Redirect to edit form.
    edit: function(product) {
      this.transitionTo('products.edit', product);
    },
    // Save and transition to /products/:product_id only if validation passes.
    save: function(product) {
      var _this = this;
      product.validate().then(function() {
        product.save();
        _this.transitionTo('products.show', product);
      });
    },
    // Roll back and transition to /products/:product_id.
    cancel: function(product) {
      product.rollback();
      this.transitionTo('products.show', product);
    },
    // Delete specified product.
    delete: function(product) {
      product.destroyRecord();
      this.transitionTo('products');
    }
  }
});
App.ProductsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  productsCount: function() {
    return this.get('model.length');
  }.property('@each')
});
App.ProductsIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.modelFor('products');
  }
});
App.ProductsIndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  needs: ['products'],
  sortProperties: ['name']
});
App.ProductsEditRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return this.store.find('product', params.product_id);
  },
  // Roll back if the user transitions away by clicking a link, clicking the
  // browser's back button, or otherwise.
  deactivate: function() {
    var model = this.modelFor('products.edit');
    if (model && model.get('isDirty') && !model.get('isSaving')) {
      model.rollback();
    }
  }
});
App.ProductsNewRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.createRecord('product');
  },
  isNew: true,
  renderTemplate: function(controller, model) {
    this.render('products.edit', {
      controller: controller
    });
  },
// Roll back if the user transitions away by clicking a link, clicking the
  // browser's back button, or otherwise.
  deactivate: function() {
    var model = this.modelFor('products.new');
    if (model && model.get('isNew') && !model.get('isSaving')) {
      model.destroyRecord();
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: When you say *Its not displaying the other part*, what specific text is not showing up? Also, if you could get this working in a JSBin /JSFiddle to the point you have it working that would give us something functional to look at .   Also see http://gist.github.com/rwjblue/8816372 for examples.

Comment: hii @EricD.Johnson it is running to a  point where you can see stock list data. It's not running after window.App = Ember.Application.create(); this command line after some research i found it is not properly integrated  as is it like a second application. I am still trying a way to integrate two ember application together is there any way to integrates two ember application together to work on same web page

Comment: Two places to look that talk about it are http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17825154/ember-js-and-multiple-single-page-apps (which encourages diff look and feel but a single app) and https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.4.0/configuring-ember/embedding-applications/ which is based on the newest version of Ember. You are currently using a very old version (1.8) and the guides only go back to 1.10 https://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/configuring-ember/embedding-applications/ .

Comment: As a general tip for Client-side frameworks, minimize what you are trying to do, and add parts back in one at a time. When you add the one thing that breaks, stop and post an simplified example of that broken thing in a JSFiddle, and others will jump in and help.

Comment: @EricD.Johnson i will sort it out as soon as possible and use latest version and try to narrow down error...but if you have any suggestion regarding how to embedded on ember app into another using div tag will be help full or any example will do as well I have seen some use of iframe but it's kind of old school approach ant thing new would be helpful

Comment: Making an Ember App inside another Ember App is an anti-pattern (something you usually should not do, as there is a better way to solve the underlying problem). If you wanted to have two ember apps in one page however, you would have to have `<div id="app1"> <div id="app2> <div/><div/>` and use `outerApp = Ember.Application.create({ rootElement: '#app1' });`  `innerApp = Ember.Application.create({ rootElement: '#app2' });`

Comment: The `<div id="app2> <div/>` could be in a .hbs template as well but if the outer app wasn't in the right route it wouldn't find that div on the page, and the `create()` would have to run after it was rendered on the DOM.

Comment: @EricD.Johnson I have tried that solution but i keep on getting this error 920 Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: You cannot use the same root element (body) multiple times in an Ember.Application.

Comment: my first app named as StockListDemoApp
// Create an Ember Application.
var StockListDemoApp = Ember.Application.create({
  rootElement: '#StockListDemoApp'
});

Comment: Second app called as App
var App = Ember.Application.create({
  rootElements: '#App'
});

Comment: And than on body ..<div id="#StockListDemo"> some template for first app </div> and than...<div id="#App">..some template for second app </div> all template have unique names but I keep getting above error

Comment: Well @pritbh , looks like you need to go back to the drawing board, or state your business need on http://discuss.emberjs.com/ for 2x Ember App wrapping. I hope you find a good solution.